# Multiple errors on installing Ubuntu after Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, partitioning, gparted

(Please even read the comments to understand better)

So let me start from the beginning.

I downloaded Ubuntu in my Windows 10 and burned it to the USB. When I restarted I saw boot options and selected `Install Linux`. I reached a step where I needed to format all the data. I closed the PC as it was very late night.

When I opened the PC next time it was showing

> ```
> Boot device not found
> ```

After many attempts I knew that I had to install Linux so I started. I selected "Erase the disk" and got the following error:

[image: Error 1]

So, I selected the "Something else" and I got these partitions:

[image: Setup 1]
 [image: Setup 2]

I also formatted the disk through the Disks tool and now they are as follows:

[image]

The GParted screenshot:

[image: Gparted]
[image]
[image]

and log

```
:======================
libparted : 2.3
======================

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 6 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 10 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 9 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 29 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 56 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 55 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 60 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 59 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 66 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 65 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 73 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 72 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 79 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 78 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 84 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 83 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 87 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 86 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 92 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 91 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 95 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:19666): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 94 was not found when attempting to remove it
/dev/sdb contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.  Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
```

command `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` gave the following result:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): D66EE60C-6D4C-4668-8DD8-94D5AAA8A182
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4077 sectors (2.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   EF00  
   2         1050624         1550335   244.0 MiB   8300  
   3         1550336       976771071   465.0 GiB   8E00
```

gdisk log :

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): n

Expert command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sda.
yWarning: The kernel is still using the old partition table.
The new table will be used at the next reboot.
The operation has completed successfully.
```

Comment: What does `gdisk -l /dev/sda` say?

Comment: @TomYan i updated the post

Comment: Weird. `gdisk` doesn't complain about the protective MBR at all. Anyway maybe you can try to create a new one with `gdisk` (`gdisk /dev/sda` -> `x` -> `n` -> `w`) and see if GParted still complains about it. I wonder why your EFI System Partition (`EF00`) is formatted as NTFS with a label of "WINRE" too...

Comment: @TomYan its the windows 10 recovery partition

Comment: @TomYan can u give me the whole command as im a noob

Comment: I already did...`gdisk /dev/sda` -> `x` -> `n` -> `w`

Comment: You should probably format the first partition to FAT32 if you want UEFI boot.

Comment: @TomYan could u please tell me how the partition table should be

Comment: @TomYan this is the result `sudo gdisk /dev/sda -> x -> n -> w
Usage: gdisk [-l] device_file`

Comment: I don't mean you should enter it as a whole line...`gdisk` is interactive...I mean run `gdisk /dev/sda`, press enter, type `x`, press enter...and so on

Comment: @TomYan could u tell how the partition table should be

Comment: The partition table is fine. It's the protective MBR (according to GParted), I am not sure what is exactly wrong with it

Comment: @see the new edit

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Legacy_MBR_.28LBA_0.29

Comment: Try to reboot and see if GParted still complains

Comment: @TomYan could u please tell how should be the partition table( here, i mean where this  specific pints like `/boot` `/` should be there)

Comment: @TomYan after running that command gparted still complains y? i think cuz im running from usb thats y and not able to make a partition table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by playing little by the command given by @TomYan

i used `sudo gdisk -> x -> z`

it wiped the whole partition and rebooted (and i was on liveusb so i just clicked restart and then enter on later screen)

it restarted i clicked "Something else"
clicked that partition made it logical then i made mount point `/`
and clicked continue it warned me about swap but i continued 
and it successfully installed

after it restarted i added the sawp partition

Comment: So is your problem fixed to your satisfaction? If so, accept your own answer. If not, please clarify what's still giving you trouble.